# Exit Spring boot service when beaninstantiationexception occurs

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

i am starting a spring boot application as below

```
@SpringBootApplication 
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.brocade")
@DependsOn("springContextManager") 
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {     
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplication(Application.class).run(args);     
    }
}
```

Also bean instantiation is done using **`@Service`** annotation in other classes. When there is beaninstantiationexception in spring boot, 
i need to exit the service using System.exit(0). From `Application.java` i am not able to get the exception.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the same but why you do you call new SpringApplication... instead of    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

Comment: But still we wont be able to get the exception in Application.java

Comment: did you try to use try..catch ?

Comment: My bad. the try catch works. i was on the track trying in Exitcodegenerator way. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, no problem

Comment: @soulcoder please consider adding solution as an answer, it will be helpful to others

Answer (score 0):

You should use try..catch block to catch and handle the exception.